# IBM BUS Change Soap Namespace of Responce

Tags: messagebroker, ibm-integration-bus

My Soap Responce like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <Response xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
            <Result>
                <Result>LOGON FAILED</Result>
            </Result>
        </Response>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

But, I need change the prefix of namespace and responce and must like this one.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <Response xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
            <Result>
                <Result>LOGON FAILED</Result>
            </Result>
        </Response>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: Have a look at this post: http://www.mqseries.net/phpBB/viewtopic.php?p=179428&sid=d0ec655d5a6aac2800f0b0cb20ee5386

Comment: The value of the namespace prefix makes no difference until they reference the same namespace, so I don't see why you would need to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using ESQL to construct your message you can do this as described here:

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSKM8N_8.0.0/com.ibm.etools.mft.doc/ac67194_.htm

```
DECLARE soapNs NAMESPACE 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/';
DECLARE tempNs NAMESPACE 'http://tempuri.org/';

SET OutputRoot.XMLNSC.soapNs:Envelope.(XMLNSC.NamespaceDecl)xmlns:soap = soapNs;
SET OutputRoot.XMLNSC.soapNs:Envelope.soapNs:Body.tempNs:Response.(XMLNSC.NamespaceDecl)xmlns = tempNs;
SET OutputRoot.XMLNSC.soapNs:Envelope.soapNs:Body.tempNs:Response.tempNs:Result.tempNs:Result = 'LOGON FAILED';
```

But still, the value of the namespace tags shouldn't make a difference.